# Http POST Requests Ionic3 - Reload data

Tags: angular, ionic3

Hello I have `ionic3` app and working width `http POST request` width my `api.php`, My functions **works good**, only I need to Reload data.

**For example:**

- I clicked `example` `function` and send request to server.
- Server must **return** some data (and this works if I will swich to other page back again)

I want show data **Immediately** and not want exit current page then go back again...

any idea? any solution? Thanks!

Data api page:

```
  public sendMessage(token, to, message, attachment){
    return this.http.post(this.sharedVars.getApi(),"action=messages/send&token="+token+"&to="+to+"&message="+message+"&attachment="+attachment, this.options
    ).map(res => res.json());
  }
```

Other Page

```
  sendMessage(id){
     let sendMsg = this.popoverCtrl.create('SendmessagePage',{data:id},{cssClass: 'comment-popover'});
     sendMsg.present();
  }
```

SendMessage Page:

```
  sendMsg(){
    this.api.sendMessage(this.user.token, this.toId, this.data.text, '1').subscribe(
        data => {
          if(data.err == 0){
            this.viewCtrl.dismiss();
            console.log(data.data);

          }
        },
        err => {
            console.log(err);
        }
    );    
  }
```

Comment: please provide some code snippet and refine your question

Comment: updated mt question....

Comment: Those are `async` functions.So you need to wait till server response.

Comment: Please refine your question. I am not able to understand your requirement.